# ubuntu /usr/bin/env: python3.6 : No such file or directory

Tags: python, ubuntu, path

First time using Ubuntu. I put the shebang as in the documentation of my hoster: `#!/usr/bin/env python3.6` which leads to "/usr/bin/env: python3.6 : No such file or directory"

```
which python3.6
>>/usr/local/bin/python3.6
```

Changing the shebang to /usr/local/bin/python3.6 gave me

```
bad interpreter: permission denied
```

I edit the file on Windows, may this be the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I guess i was not clear: That is what I tried first, then I got the error "bad interpreter: permission denied"

Comment: Did you try replacing the shebang with **#!/usr/local/bin/python3.6**

Comment: yes, that gave me: "bad interpreter: permission denied"

Comment: Sorry, your comment was right @Kyle. 
I tried  #!/usr/local/bin python3.6, which lead to the error. Thank you.